# Editing Wordpress category gives PHP line/parse error

Tags: php, wordpress

Not sure when this occurred but when editing a category, this error is given at the top of the edit category page.

> Warning: call_user_func_array() expects parameter 1 to be a valid
>   callback, function 'my_category_custom_fields' not found or invalid
>   function name in /home2/sirenon2/public_html/wp-includes/plugin.php on
>   line 525

Line 525 is `call_user_func_array($the_['function'], array_slice($args, 0, (int) $the_['accepted_args']));`

When I submit on the edit category page, it gives me the original error plus:

> Warning: Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by
>   (output started at
>   /home2/sirenon2/public_html/wp-includes/plugin.php:525) in
>   /home2/sirenon2/public_html/wp-includes/pluggable.php on line 1228

Line 1228 is `header("Location: $location", true, $status);`.

Any ideas on what the problem is and how to fix it? I do have custom fields on my edit category pages.

Thanks

Comment: For the second error (Headers already sent), check out [this StackOverflow](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8028957/how-to-fix-headers-already-sent-error-in-php).

Answer (score 0):

Either one of installed plugins has error which is throwing above error or you need to update wordpress or PHP. There may be compatibility issue of WordPress with installed PHP version. Few of WordPress's functions might have been updated.

If updating doesn't works, simply go to wp-config.php file and set this constant to false. If this line is not there into config file, add it.

```
define('WP_DEBUG', false);
```

Answer (score 0):

I also have this problem before. But I change output_buffering to On. You can find it from PHP.ini.

Or refer this url http://chevronscode.com/index.php/wordpress-header-error-wp-includespluggable-php.html